Modifying VS Code's Dev Container settings to work with Podman instead of Docker
I am using the Dev Container extension for VS Code on a RHEL8 desktop, and am trying to modify its settings so that it can work with Podman instead of Docker.
On VS Code's "Advanced Containers" page, under "Docker options" (https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/docker-options), they acknowledge that certain Docker functions are still incompatible with Podman, and suggest the following fix:

To work around issues with rootless Podman (for example, not respecting a non-root "remoteUser" and trying to install the server in root), you can set the following:

"runArgs": [
  "--userns=keep-id"
],
"containerEnv": {
  "HOME": "/home/node"
}


"remoteUser" can be used when "HOME" is set because Dev Containers gives that setting precedence over the home folder it finds in /etc/passwd.

I am quite new to working with all of these tools, and would like to know where these settings are to be added/amended. Is it a VS Code setting, and if so, how can I navigate to it? Thanks!

Found this question looking for the answer myself.
Add those options to your devcontainer.json and from the VS Code command palette, trigger a rebuild of the container.
See the options here:
https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/

Thanks for responding! My work on containers is parked for now, but I'll give it a shot when I resume working with them!

Here is what worked for me after having researched this quite a bit :
"runArgs": [
    "--userns=keep-id"
],
"containerUser": "vscode",
"updateRemoteUserUID": true,
"containerEnv": {
    "HOME": "/home/vscode"
}

And also check out the Pod Manager extension which greatly facilitates Podman container management in VSCode. Good luck !
